# Using a BodyParser with an authenticated request in Play 2.2.1 Framework

Tags: scala-2.10, playframework-2.2

So, my authentication process is asynchronous. I need upload file but, I don't know how I can add **'multipart/form-data' BodyParser** parameter to action.

**This is Secured trait:**

```
trait Secured {

  private def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get("email")

  private def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.Auth.login)

  def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Future[SimpleResult]) =
    Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
      Action.async { request =>
        f(user)(request)
      }
    }
}
```

**I'm trying this:**

```
  def IsAuthenticated(b: BodyParser[AnyContent] = parse.anyContent)(f: => String =>
  Request[AnyContent] => Future[SimpleResult]) = 
  Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
    Action(b).async { request =>
      f(user)(request)
    }
  }
```

**but, did not work.**

**in Controller:**

```
def upload = IsAuthenticated { _ => implicit request =>
  request.body.moveTo(new File("/tmp/picture/uploaded"))
  Future.successful(Ok("File uploaded"))
}
```

**Anybody knows how to make it?**

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to write in your Auth method like this:

```
def IsAuthenticated[A](b: BodyParser[A])(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Future[SimpleResult]) = 
  Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
  Action.async { request =>
    f(user)(request)
  }
}
```

And then You may upload with this way in Controller:

```
def upload = IsAuthenticated(parse.temporaryFile) {_ => implicit request =>
  val mfData = request.body.asMultipartFormData
  Future.successful {
    mfData.map { tempFile =>
      tempFile.file("picture").map { file =>
        val filePath = new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "/test.png"
        file.ref.moveTo(new File(filePath), true)
        Logger.info("File successfully received to:" + filePath + " folder")
        Ok("File uploaded")
      }.getOrElse {
        Redirect(routes.Application.uploadWindow()).flashing("error" -> "Missing file")
      }
    }.get
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you tried `Action.async(b)` instead of `Action(b).async`?

Comment: this happened: "Cannot resolve symbol async" and "Missing parameter type: request" errors. And If you have a question please write to "Comment" not as answer